Two nginx servers on different ports
I am a front-end developer with some DevOps skills. Currently, I am using my MacBook Pro (M1) for website development. I have set up two user accounts on my MacBook: one for my freelance projects and the other for my work as an employee.
For my freelance projects, I utilize Laravel Valet as my local development environment, which works exceptionally well. Initially, I attempted to use Laravel Valet for my employee work as well. However, after encountering some challenges, I realized that Valet isn't designed for a multi-user environment.
Consequently, I decided to switch to Docker for my employee work. As a result, I have configured Docker for one of the websites (http://move.test):
docker-compose.yml
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3.8"
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: 
      context: ./docker/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      - ./httpdocs:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php

  php:
    container_name: php
    build: 
      context: ./docker/php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./httpdocs:/var/www/html

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.32
    container_name: mysql
    env_file:
      - ./docker/mysql/.env
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./database/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: pma
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 300M
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8085:80

nginx Dockerfile:
# docker/nginx/Dockerfile
FROM nginx:1.23
ADD default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

default.conf (nginx config):
# docker/nginx/default.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.htm index.html;

    root /var/www/html;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}

php Dockerfile:
# docker/php/Dockerfile
FROM php:8.3-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli

This configuration works smoothly when accessing http://move.test:8080/ or http://move.test:8080/wp-admin. However, my goal is to access http://move.test without specifying the port number. The complication arises because it seems that 127.0.0.1:80 is already in use by Valet on my other (freelance) user account.
Is there a method to associate the domain move.test with port 8080, allowing me to access http://move.test without including the port number?
Perhaps there's a straightforward solution that I'm not aware of due to my limited expertise.

You can only have one program listening on port 80. You can let your move.test Nginx listen on port 80 and route the move.test traffic one way and other traffic to Laravel Valet. Or vice versa. You can also stick a new reverse proxy in front of both systems, if you want to keep your systems separate.
